# FullCalendar: Keep day properties after next/previous click

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, repaint

I'm using FullCalendar as an interface for users to schedule appointments. When I load the calendar, I paint individual days based on the number of appointments already scheduled on that day. Here's the code:

```
 function paintCalendar (dailyPercentage) {
    $.each(dailyPercentage, function(){
            if (this.percentage >= 65) {
                $cell = $('td.fc-future[data-date="' + this.date.substring(0, 10) + '"]');
                $cell.addClass('fc-high-traffic');
                $calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            } else if (this['percentage'] >= 35) {
                $cell = $('td.fc-future[data-date="' + this.date.substring(0, 10) + '"]');
                $cell.addClass('fc-medium-traffic');
                $calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            }

    });
}
```

Each of the classes I add simply has a background-color associated with it.

However, when a user clicks the prev, next, or today buttons, the calendar is completely reloaded and my added classes are removed.

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374143/fullcalendar-keep-event-properties-after-previous-next-click) but his solution involved passing additional data in the event objects themselves. I'm dealing with the days themselves which aren't passed through.

Is there any way I can trigger an event after the calendar is refreshed similar to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272005/jquery-full-calendar-callback-after-the-calendar-has-loaded-completely)?

My function works just fine I just need an event to trigger its execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272005/jquery-full-calendar-callback-after-the-calendar-has-loaded-completely) fits the problem. I just added the trigger in different places to handle specific changes to suit my issue.

**fullcalendar.js**

```
function prev() {
    renderView(-1);
    trigger('complete', null, true);
}


function next() {
    renderView(1);
    trigger('complete', null, true);
}


function today() {
    date = new Date();
    renderView();
    trigger('complete', null, true);
}
```

**my javascript**

```
complete: function () {
        paintCalendar(dailyPercentage);
    }
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, have a look at [eventAfterRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/). It might be suited to your situation and certainly be better than changing the source (which will give you issues if you ever upgrade and forgot about the modifications you made)

Comment: +1 for good suggestions. I don't think _eventAfterRender_ is quite what I'm looking for, so I will just document my changes very well

Comment: Apologies, I labeled the link incorrectly, it should read [eventAfterAllRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) or [eventAfterRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/).

I don't fully understand your question but you can certainly use these callbacks to add classes to your events

Also refetchEvents probably shouldn't be used within a loop as this will likely result in multiple calls to the server

Comment: Thanks but I already figured it out. My problem did not have to do with events but the individual days themselves. I would use this function to add a background color for that cell and when I would navigate, the calendar cells would be reset. Your last point was good though, I will move that refresh call.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is event div object is re-rendering and missing the previously set item like background color and classes, take a look in to  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/